# I can't open a content source in search serviceapplication?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search, content-source

Here i tried to start crawl but its not working,I got this type of error

```
Sorry, something went wrong
System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '2bfd134a-72d2-424a-825c-04d1f8e9e1d9' in search application 'Search Service Application' is in a good state and try again. 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application) 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApiFactory.CreateSearchApi(SearchServiceApplication application) 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ContentSourceCollection..ctor(Content parent) 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_ContentSources() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.WebControls.ListContentSourcesControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
TECHNICAL DETAILS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your Search Application Topology on the start page of your Search Service Application:

[image]

If not every component is green, then you have a problem which may be hard to solve. You have to check Manage Services on Server and see that the appropriate services is Started. If they are, and you still have errors, the fastest way to solve this is to recreate the Search Service Application in my experience.

Comment: @SuriyaadevanBalu Wou're welcome :)